# Unable to initialize Git; AggregateError(2) Error: Unable to find git Error: Unable to find git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-extensions

Iam getting this in my visual studio code no matter how many time I try to reinstall it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you using macOS? In my case, the error is caused by NOT agreed the Xcode agreement.

Answer (score 30):

I had this exact problem with VSCode 1.72.2 on macOS after a holiday. It then turned out that Xcode had been updated. It required me to agree to a new license agreement before using git.

Starting Xcode, accepting the agreement and reloading VSCode solved the issue for me.

---

Edit: I noticed just now that this has been pointed out by [@r0n9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2185248/r0n9) already

Answer (score 9):

In my case `xcode-select` was already available on my terminal.

But I had to run the following command, then the error was solved:

```bash
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: This command worked for me as well!

Answer (score 5):

I used to get this error in my MAC after installing the newer upgrade Ventura 13.0.

It got resolved after accepting XCode License as mentioned by @r0n9 and @Kim Ferrari in the previous comments.

Here are the commands that I used to accept the License and the agreement.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have installed git client ?

https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31763573)

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to Ventura 13.0 I had the same problem. Tried to fix it by running Xcode and accepting the agreements there, but only installing git with brew solved my problem

`brew install git`

Answer (score 1):

I also use

```
brew install git
```

to fix the same problem, when i updated my MAC after installing the newer upgrade Ventura 13.0.

https://git-scm.com/download/mac

Answer (score -1):

Use the code,

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

On the second command follow the instruction and tap 'space', once you reach the end of the license agreement you just have to agree by typing 'agree' in the terminal.

Close the terminal and restart VS Code, magic reveals.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74225512/2227743).

Answer (score -1):

It happened with me when I updated my XCode. I resolved it by navigating to

> Xcode > Preferences > Location > Command Line Tools

When you select Command Line Tools, it asked for my system password and then VS Code git started working after a reload.

Answer (score -1):

Mine was solved with a download, windows system, did not exist on the machine. It would never work anyway.afffffff

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).